# Migration flags should be more general than "questions about computer-based games"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, video-games

Recently, I flagged a question about a console game (*The Legend of Zelda: Wind Waker*) as off-topic for this site. However, I noticed that the flags I had to choose from were as follows:

[image]

Both flags say that they are for questions about "computer-based games". However in this case the question wasn't about a computer-based game, but rather a console-based game. So technically the flag wasn't the right one to use.

Arqade and Game Development Stack Exchange don't limit themselves to just computer-based games. Given that this is the case, and that we may from time to time need to migrate console-based game questions, I think that the flag ought to be broadened to something more general that encompasses console-based games. I'd like to suggest the following alternative:

- Questions about **video games**, including video games that are roleplaying games...

I like this one because it is a simple term that, [according to Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/video_game#English), encompasses both computer-based and console-based games. Other options might be:

- Questions about **computer-based and console-based games**, including computer-based and console-based roleplaying games...
- Questions about **non-tabletop games**, including computer-based and console-based roleplaying games...

Is this something that we might be able to change?

(Also while we're at it, the first flag does not have a comma before the "but", but the second one does. They should be consistent).

Comment: Technically "non-tabletop games" includes LARPs, which are on topic, so we shouldn't use that one ;)

Comment: Technically, consoles are computers, too. Just not personal computers.

Comment: Actually, [Wikipedia defines video game consoles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_console) as distinct from home computers (pretty much the only type of computer that a video game would be played on). But we're splitting hairs here; either way the current term "computer-based games" isn't broad enough.

Comment: LARP is ontopic!? That is so cool! - never knew

Comment: @Anaphory, since this discussion is marked completed, maybe it would be better to create a new meta topic on it.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Done, separate question now at http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/migration-flags-should-be-more-general-than-questions-about-video-games

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**We should change it to "video game," really.**

- "Video game" is a term everyone understands.
- "Video game" covers consoles, personal computers, and handhelds.
- Arqade [self-describes](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) as a "video game" site. As far as I can tell, they don't cover computer-based games that aren't video games.
- Game Dev [self-describes](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as a site for "video/computer game developers."

Comment: Hokay. We're in the process of changing it. It requires a golden-eye like activation though, so it'll be a while while we get someone dressed like James Bond.

Comment: I'm afraid, Mr. Bond, that your off-topic requests have been... fully implemented.